# How do I enable icon setting in Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

How do I enable this inspect element in Google Chrome? The part that is enclosed in red box.

[image: expected-result]

Because right now, by default, this is what I see with my inspect element.

[image: actual-result]

Do I need to install something or this is within settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshots are from different browser dev tools. If m not wrong, the top one is on Firefox where the bottom one is Chrome.

- The **Inspector** tab is similar to the **Elements** tab in Chrome
- The **Debugger** tab is similar to the **Sources** tab in Chrome

Comment: I see, makes sense. Thanks for clarifying this.